# Voice enabled RollerSkill BOT application not working in WebChat

Tags: bots, botframework, web-chat

Microsoft has provided some sample applications of Speech To Text & Vice-versa in GitHub.
I am using **demo-RollerSkill** sample code. I have hosted this application in our environment and created new BOT using dev.BotFramework.com.

As you all may know that this application is in C#.net

I am facing below challenge,

This application voice commands(Speech To Text & Vice versa) works fine in emulator but in **WebChat channel, it does not show MIC icon**.

So is voice command at the moment supports only node.js BOT?

Any quick help is appreciable.

Thank you.

Comment: If you are using chrome read the note halfway down the page [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/channel-connect-webchat-speech).

Comment: Enabling Speech - https://blog.botframework.com/2017/10/11/customize-web-chat-websites/

Comment: Thank you Jason and Kien